# Why haven't I achieved cultural victory yet?

Tags: civilization-6

I seem to meet the requirements for cultural victory, by having more tourists than everyone, but I still haven't won yet. Cultural victory is enabled, so that isn't the issue, but I have received a popup saying one of the other civilizations is close to cultural dominance, though I don't see how that is possible (see picture below).

[image]

Comment: Are those all the players? In order to win you must have more **foreign tourists** than *any* other player has **domestic tourists**.

Comment: @n_palum, do I not have 1591 foreign tourists? the next highest player has 1342 domestic tourists. all those listed, are the civilizations that haven't been completely wiped out yet.

Comment: It's weird that you haven't gotten it yet. You have 2404 Domestic, 1591 Foreign and the closest Civ's Domestic amount is 1342. The only requirement is to be your foreign > any other domestic.

Comment: I have to ask, are cultural victories enabled? I always disabled mine because I'm a hateful warmonger who wants the delight of annihilating my enemies. Perhaps you accidentally disabled them, or forgot? (just saw the question is almost 2 years old, but my comment still stands. Ever figure it out?)

Comment: @TimS., i probably still have the game saved somewhere, I can potentially check. that is a good thing to check. i dont recall ever disabling that though

Comment: If Cultural Victory was disabled you wouldn't be able to see that screen ....